# Isuue handling handlebars

Tags: javascript, frontend, handlebars.js, web-frontend

I tried to access the elemnts created by handlebars by clicking on the buttons. but it takes first element it created. Please help me with this one

```
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <div>
        <table id="cartItem">
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>count</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Id</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="demo">
       {{#each this}}
          <h2 id="name">{{stock_name}}</h2>
          <h2 id="id" style="display: none;">{{stock_id}}</h2>
          <h4 id="price">{{stock_price}}</h4>
          <button class="btn" onclick="placeOrder()"></button>
       {{/each}}
    </script>
    <script src="Asset/js/Handle.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script> 
    <script src="Asset/js/placeOrder.js"></script>
</body>
```

Handle.js file contains code below,

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/api/stocks');
request.onload = function(){
    if(request.status>=200 && request.status<400){
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    createHTML(data);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Error from server");
    }
};

request.onerror = function(){
    console.log("There is an error");
}

request.send();

function createHTML(jsonData){
console.log("testing.......")
console.log(jsonData);

var template = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
var GenerateHTML = compiledTemplate(jsonData);

var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML= GenerateHTML;
}
```

Placeorder.js contains code below

```
function placeOrder(){
    var i_Stocks =  document.getElementById("name").textContent;
    var i_price =  document.getElementById("price").textContent;
    var i_Id = document.getElementById("id").textContent;
   

    console.log(i_Stocks);
    console.log(i_price);
   
    var table = document.getElementById("cartItem");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var name = row.insertCell(0);
  var count = row.insertCell(1);
  var price = row.insertCell(2);
  var id = row.insertCell(3);
  name.innerHTML = i_Stocks;
  price.innerHTML = i_price;
  count.innerHTML = 1;
  id.innerHTML = i_Id;
}
```

the Json request returns,

[{"stock_id":"stk0001","stock_name":"popsickle","stock_price":45,"stock_status":"yes"},{"stock_id":"stk0002","stock_name":"icecream","stock_price":66,"stock_status":"yes"},{"stock_id":"stk0003","stock_name":"oreo","stock_price":60,"stock_status":"yes"},{"stock_id":"stk0004","stock_name":"jellyBears","stock_price":40,"stock_status":"yes"},{"stock_id":"stk0005","stock_name":"cakes","stock_price":70,"stock_status":"no"}]

Comment: You're creating elements with the same IDs (name, id and price) for each item in your data list. HTML element IDs need to be unique to be valid.

Comment: How should I get the data I want from the templates..?

Comment: I think you need a way to determine which item is selected. I think you should pass the item's index to `placeOrder`. Your template would then include `onclick="placeOrder({{ @index }})"` and you would use that index arg to get the correct item from your items array.